# Getting user's location with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm currently trying to get a user's current location with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)askForLocation:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"here");
    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *point, NSError *err){
        NSLog(@"callback");
        NSLog(@"point: %@",point);
    }];
}
```

When the function is called, it prints "here", but never prints "callback" or any error indicating there was a problem. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've installed `Parse` correctly, as I can create a new user correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good possibility that you need to add the following key in your info.plist...

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The text you want to appear to the user to access their location.</string>
```

This is the same as if you were simply using CLLocation. [NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26) is a new requirement as of iOS 8.

Comment: Try setting the key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` since you are using this in the background.

Comment: Also, you may have inadvertently disabled location for the app. Check the privacy - location settings.

Comment: What Fogmeister said. Also, if you're testing in the simulator, make sure you have a fake location set. This can be set under Debug->Location.

Comment: @timgcarlson my apologies this did actually fix my problem. I accidentally selected Privacy - Location Usage Description which is NSLocationUsageDescription instead of NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.